# Getting ERR. Connection Refused error in console after deploying project in server?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills

I am getting following error in my console when I deploy my code in server using

> ng serve --prod

command.My project is still running without any problem. I want to get rid of these errors. what to do?

> polyfills.1845d863ad5d7590138d.bundle.js:1 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1511331693715
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Please provide the solution ?

Comment: probably a CORS problem. More info re needed in order to understand the problem